Notification bell is not showing next to the clock in Ubuntu 22.04
The small bell icon that is supposed to show next to the clock on my desktop whenever I get an email or a message on Slack is not showing.
The notification bell is not showing next to the clock in Ubuntu 22.04. What should I install/reinstall to make it come back?
I am using Ubuntu 22.04. When I press Super+V, I do see the list of notifications, but the small bell icon is not there.

